# How a video forwarded many times is stored as a single copy in Database?

Tags: encryption, data-structures, storage

If we take an example of WhatsApp messenger, we have end to end encryption and middleman cannot see the data. If a user sends a video to any other user, and that video is forwarded again to a different user, how do we maintain a single copy of the video instead of having redundant copies for every forward?

Comment: This answer in Cryptography.SE may help you. [Securely “forwarding” a Large message in a hybrid encryption system without sending the actual message](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77832/18298). This is common way.

Comment: Why do you think that there is only one copy?

Comment: [Encryption background: What is key wrapping?](https://www.frankhissen.de/encryption-what-is-key-wrapping-frank-hissen-it-blog.html)

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you. I am looking for a general answer, using some data structure if possible.

Comment: @cassandrad I don't think storing the same data multiple times is feasible. It will be a waste of storage as we are storing redundant data.